# I’ve lost my luggages at SFO port of entry and my destination is DAL. Where should I file a property irregularity report?

Tags: lost-luggage

My route was
SGN to ICN with Asiana Airline
ICN to SFO with Asiana Airline
And SFO to DAL with Alaska Airline
The law was I have to pick my checked bags up from the conveyer at SFO before go through Customs and Immigration for a scan and then drop them for Alaska and fly home. 
What happened was all my bags have never appeared on the conveyer at SFO so I was not able to bring them to my connecting flight to DAL. An agent there told me that I need to reach my destination, which is DAL, and file a report. But is it true? Or should I file the report immediately at SFO?

Comment: What did you end up doing...and was your luggage ever delivered to you?